# margin auto not working

Tags: html, css

Here is the html and the css in a snippet:

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    header {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #35424a;
        border-bottom: #e8491d 5px solid;
    }
    
    h1 {
        float: left;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .acme {
        color: #e8491d;
    }
    
    nav {
        float: right;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }
    
    li {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 150%;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <header>
            <h1><span class="acme">Acme </span>Web Design</h1>
    
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>HOME</li>
                    <li>ABOUT</li>
                    <li>SERVICES</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is with h1 and nav I set the top and bottom margin to auto and gave the header a height of 100px (105px with the border) and even though margin auto still not working I tried to add

```
display: block;
```

but again still no thing happens

Comment: All you want to align the nav items to center right?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to update your `header` CSS to :

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;  
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #35424a;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 5px solid;
}
```

That fix the problem

Comment: @KadiemHaider Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

-> Please attached following code into your attached files.

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    header {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #35424a;
        border-bottom: #e8491d 5px solid;
    }
    
    h1 {
        float: left;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .acme {
        color: #e8491d;
    }
    
    nav {
        float: right;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }
    
    li {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 150%;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    .display-table {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .vertical-content {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Stack</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <header>
            <div class="display-table">
                <div class="vertical-content">
                    <h1><span class="acme">Acme </span>Web Design</h1>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>HOME</li>
                            <li>ABOUT</li>
                            <li>SERVICES</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
             </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTML does not work with margin-top or margin-bottom, you need to create a flex display, check this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For what you want, you need to do this:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

And if you need something else from flex, check the link